# Method whereHas does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got 2 tables which have relationships using Eloquent of which I'm attempting to **filter** based on requests.

```
+----------+---------+
| Table 1            |
+----------+---------+
| id       | rl_id   |
+----------+---------+
| 39       | 2       |
| 40       | 234     |
| 41       | 345     |
+----------+---------+

+----------+---------+
| Table 2 - rl       |
+----------+---------+
| id       | type    |
+----------+---------+
| 2        | Hel..   |
| 234      | Umb...  |
| 345      | Pot.    |
+----------+---------+
```

I've got 2 Models:

```
Class Listing extends Model {

    protected $table = 'listings';

    public function rocketleague()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\RocketLeague');
    }

}

Class Game extends Model {

    protected $table = 'games';

    public function listings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Listing');
    }

}

Class RocketLeague extends Model {

    protected $table = 'rl_items';

}
```

How I'm getting the error is via this:

```
$game = Game::find($game_id);
$game->listings = Listing::where('game_id', $game_id)->get();

//I perform a filter here based on request
$type = "Hel...";
$game->listings->whereHas('rocketleague', function($q) use($type) {
    $q->where('type', $type);
})->get();
```

And then I'm being given the following upon the query being performed:

```
(1/1)BadMethodCallException
Method whereHas does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your mistake is here:

```
$game->listings = Listing::where('game_id', $game_id)->get();
```

when you add `->get()` to your eloquent query it gets results from database, and returns them as collection, I think you need to try without `->get()` before applying `whereHas`

Comment: That's appeared to work to an extent, but why after this query is it trying to access a table that doesn't exist? `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_database.listing_rocket_league' doesn't exist`

Comment: maybe it doesn't exist? have you checked for typos?

Comment: it's not supposed to be accessing this table, the only tables are `rl_items`, `games` & `listings`

Comment: I've updated my **Models** in the question to give you a better overview of the tables that I actually have

Comment: it's searching for table with this weird name because of relations you created, are you sure you need that relation work this way? also you can specify relation table name as parameter to hasMany, belongsToMany etc, so laravel won't assume that table is named table_a_table_b but you can specity any name

Comment: you are correct! it was indeed needed to be `belongsTo` inside the Listing model

Answer (score 0):

wherehas fails because after your first query $game is a collection and not a model

Should be something like:

```
$filteredListing = 
Listing::where('game_id', $game_id)->whereHas('rocketleague', function($q) use($type) {
    $q->where('type', $type);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$game->listings->whereHas('rocketleague', function($q) use($type) {
    $q->where('type', $type);
})->get();
```

with

```
$game->listings->newQuery()->whereHas('rocketleague', function($q) use($type) {
    $q->where('type', $type);
});
```